# Comma before "while"

Tags: commas

I've been taught that while proceeded by a comma means "whereas", and that when it is not, is interpreted to mean "at the same time".

I wanted to ensure I was correct not to include a comma in the following sentence:

> I was also reminded of the importance of using empathy while still
>   maintaining a position of clinical neutrality.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your sentence is correct.

Don't text while driving. Same idea with fewer modifiers and an intransitive verb.

Answer (score 0):

The 'rule' doesn't properly cover subtleties.

> He spoke passionately about the importance of using empathy while
>   still maintaining a position of clinical neutrality.

is actually ambiguous, but the default reading corresponds to the one you indicate. 'His' topic was *The importance of using empathy while
still maintaining a position of clinical neutrality.*

However, with the addition of the comma,

> He spoke passionately about the importance of using empathy, while
>   still maintaining a position of clinical neutrality.

means

> While still maintaining a position of clinical neutrality, he spoke passionately about the importance of using empathy.

In none of these is the 'whereas' sense in play.

In your example, only the 'What came to my mind was *The importance of using empathy while still maintaining a position of clinical neutrality*' reading makes sense, so the comma should be omitted.